# Ensure InputBox date entry is in mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: vba, excel

My code runs, however, I found that when user enters dd/mm/**yy**, it is accepted when it should not.

How can I trap if the user does not enter mm/dd/yyyy?

```vb
Dim LastReportDate As String
Dim StartDate As String

reTry:

LastReportDate = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/dd/yyyy", "Date Range Validated:", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy"))

'User Presses "Cancel"
If StrPtr(LastReportDate) = 0 Then MsgBox "Cancel button pressed, Data Range Validated - Range (B3) will be blank.", vbCritical, "User Cancelled Date Entry": Exit Sub

'If user does not enter anthying restart at 0
If LastReportDate = vbNullString And StrPtr(LastReportDate) > 0 Then MsgBox "You entered no string": GoTo reTry

'If user did enter a date, then go validate it
If LastReportDate <> vbNullString Then: GoTo ValidateDateFormat

ValidateDateFormat:
'User Entered a Valid Date
If IsDate(LastReportDate) Then

    'Put start date - end date in B3
    'Note start date = -6 days: Data Range Validation is one week
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).cells(3, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", -6, LastReportDate) & " - " & LastReportDate
    'If user entered wrong date format then go to 0
Else
    MsgBox "Wrong Date Format": GoTo reTry
End If
```

Comment: compare the date formats too, `If Format(LastReportDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") = LastReportDate Then`

Comment: `If LastReportDate <> vbNullString Then: GoTo ValidateDateFormat` - the instructions separator is redundant/confusing, and the `ValidateDateFormat` label runs regardless of whether you `GoTo`-jump or not. Also, consider making a custom UserForm instead of an `InputBox`; you'll have much better control over validation and everything. ...and consider a better looping strategy than a `GoTo` loop.

Comment: @cyboashu, that works perfectly, Format(LastReportDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") <> LastReportDate , traps the user to only enter mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, That section checks whether or not the user did enter a date, if they did enter a date, then we jump to validate it if the date meets format requirement.

Comment: Sure. What I'm saying is that regardless of whether or not `LastReportDate <> vbNullString`, the next line to execute is under the same label you're jumping to, which makes the whole condition useless/redundant: the jump isn't needed because you end up there regardless of the conditional.

Comment: Also, *trapping the user* might be considered unethical in some jurisdictions ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug `Sub TrapUser() : Do : Loop : End Sub`

Comment: @Mat'sMug `On User GoTo Label`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all that jumping about using `GoTo` how about using a loop.

This will prompt the user until they enter a valid date in the correct format or hit `Cancel`.

```
Dim LastReportDate As String
Dim StartDate As String
Dim boolValidDate

    Do

        LastReportDate = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/dd/yyyy", "Date Range Validated:", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy"))

        'User Presses "Cancel"
        If StrPtr(LastReportDate) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Cancel button pressed, Data Range Validated - Range (B3) will be blank.", vbCritical, "User Cancelled Date Entry"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        boolValidDate = Format(LastReportDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") = LastReportDate

        If Not boolValidDate Then
            MsgBox "Wrong Date Format"
        ElseIf IsDate(LastReportDate) Then
            'Put start date - end date in B3
            'Note start date = -6 days: Data Range Validation is one week
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", -6, LastReportDate) & " - " & LastReportDate
        End If

    Loop Until boolValidDate

    MsgBox "CFR Macro Completed.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Macro Status: Successful"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LastReportDate As String
Dim StartDate As String

reTry:

LastReportDate = InputBox("Insert date in format mm/dd/yyyy", "Date Range Validated:", Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy"))

'User Presses "Cancel"
If StrPtr(LastReportDate) = 0 Then MsgBox "Cancel button pressed, Data Range Validated - Range (B3) will be blank.", vbCritical, "User Cancelled Date Entry": Exit Sub

'If user does not enter anthying restart at 0
If LastReportDate = vbNullString And StrPtr(LastReportDate) > 0 Then MsgBox "You entered no string": GoTo reTry

'If user did enter a date, then go validate it
If LastReportDate <> vbNullString Then: GoTo ValidateDateFormat


ValidateDateFormat:

'Trap user if the user did not enter the required format
'Thanks @cyboashu
If Format(LastReportDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") <> LastReportDate Then
MsgBox "Wrong Date Format": GoTo reTry

'User Entered a Valid Date
ElseIf IsDate(LastReportDate) Then

     'Put start date - end date in B3
     'Note start date = -6 days: Data Range Validation is one week
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).cells(3, 2).Value = DateAdd("d", -6, LastReportDate) & " - " & LastReportDate
     'If user entered wrong date format then go to 0
Else
End If

MsgBox "CFR Macro Completed.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Macro Status: Successful"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B4") = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B2").Select
```